# Celery start worker and beats at once

Tags: celery

Got stuck for a while using custom scheduler for celery beats:

```
celery -A myapp worker -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler -E -B -l info
```

My though was that this would launch both celery `worker` and celery `beats` using the `redbeat.RedBeatScheduler` as its scheduler. It even says `beat: Staring..`, however it does not use the specified scheduler apparently. No cron tasks are executed like this.

However when I split this command into separate `worker` and `beats`, that means

```
celery -A myapp worker -E -l info
celery -A myapp beat -S redbeat.RedBeatScheduler
```

Everything works as expected.

Is there any way to merge those two commands?

Comment: Try to run `celery -A myapp worker --scheduler redbeat.RedBeatScheduler -E -B -l info` .

Comment: @DejanLekic That actually works, thanks! Feel free to post it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think the Celery worker has the `-S` parameter like beat does. Here is what --helps says:

> --scheduler SCHEDULER
> Scheduler class to use. Default is
> celery.beat.PersistentScheduler

So I suggest you use the --scheduler option and run `celery -A myapp worker --scheduler redbeat.RedBeatScheduler -E -B -l info` instead.